Referencing a JPA entity with an id instead of a Java reference
Is it possible to reference another JPA entity with an id
instead of a Java reference?
We have this entity which references a Person entity.
Instead of having the referencePerson property we would
want it to replace with a referencePersonId property
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID")
public class PersonReference {

    @Id
    private Long id;

  
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Person referencePerson;
}

new version should look similar to this
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID")
public class PersonReference {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    // reference Person entity somehow
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Long referencePersonId;
}

Is it possible with JPA to have that with a foreign key constraint and
cascaded delete, that is when a Person object with a given
id is deleted also matching PersonReference entities are deleted
